# How to stop Image rotation using BitmapFactory once camera takes photograph?

Tags: java, android

When I have captured a photograph with the camera on my Pixel 3XL, it rotates 90 degrees when displaying in the following page (in this instance `EditorActivity.class`)

I have tried to fix this by simply adding a flipIMage method but it does not appear to do anything...

```
 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/photoTemp.png");
                        flipIMage(bitmap);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditorActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
```

flipIMage is;

```
public static Bitmap flipIMage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        int rotation = fixOrientation(bitmap);
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);
        matrix.preScale(-1, 1);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

If it helps, my cameraClicked method is here;

```
public void cameraClicked(View view) {


        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/photoTemp.png");
        try {
            tempFile.createNewFile();
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    this.getApplicationContext()
                            .getPackageName() + ".provider", tempFile);
            //install.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`fixOrientation` method;

```
private static int fixOrientation(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
            return 90;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

EditorActivity;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        

            //
        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);
        
        Bitmap bitmap = MainActivity.bitmap;
        
        //
        
        
        
        
        
        btnDoneOrEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDoneOrEdit);
        btnChangeMask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeMask);
        
        editorImage = (EditorImage)findViewById(R.id.editorImage);
        editorImage.setBitmapImage(bitmap);
        editorImage.setTopPanel((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.topPanel));
        editorImage.setBottomPanel((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomPanel));
        gridview_zombie = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView_zombie);
        linearcontent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_content);
```

Comment: Where is fixOrientation() method ?

Comment: Now added the fixOrientation() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reload the image on the `editor.class` you can try checking the EXIF data on the image and rotating the image before displaying.

To get the path from the Bitmap use:

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}

     public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bitmap, String path) throws IOException {
        int rotate = 0;
        ExifInterface exif;
        exif = new ExifInterface(path);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
        }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotate);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

You can then use the returned Bitmap and display that.

So your call stack would be

```
  Uri uri = getimageUri(this, MainActivity.Bitmap);
  String path = getRealPathFromUri(uri);
  Bitmap rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(MainActivity.Bitmap, path);
  editorImage.setBitmapImage(bitmap);
```

Comment: the `onCreate` method for the `EditorActivity` shows;

`Bitmap bitmap = MainActivity.bitmap`

If I use your method above for checking the EXIF, it works except It is looking to find the `(path)` it won't let me put bitmap inside that `(path)` ?

Comment: Can you post the `EditorActivity`?

Comment: see my updated answer I couldn't fit the two methods in a comment.

Comment: Thanks TDIScott, the only issue I have is this line `exif = new ExifInterface(path);` I can't figure out what to put inside the `(path)` ?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear you would call `getImageUri(this, bitmap )` where `bitmap` is `MainActivity.bitmap` and use the returned URI and pass that over too `getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri)` and the returned String value is the path you pass `rotateimage()`

Ill reformat the answer so it is easier to follow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217596/discussion-between-user1695971-and-tdiscott).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           //check the rotation of the image and display it properly
            ExifInterface exif;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                if (orientation == 6) {
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                } else if (orientation == 3) {
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                } else if (orientation == 8) {
                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                    Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                }
                scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                        scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                        true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Use scaledBitmap for further process.